# Disable cPanel login through other domain on same server

Tags: linux, login, cpanel, whm

On a WHM server I have many hosting accounts. Currently the users are able to open their cPanel on any domain which is hosted on same vps by providing their own root credentials.

Let me explain; for example:

- the 'root' user at domain1.com has password abc
- the 'root' user at domain2.com has password xyz

What happens is;

the root user of domain1.com can sign in to domain2.com/cpanel using user root and password xyz.

Although the user sees the correct cpanel contents of domain2.com but still it is opened on domain1.com which I think is wrong.

Is there any setting or configuration in cPanel so that users can only sign in to the cPanel only on their own domain name?

Answer (score 0):

cPanel does not discriminate between domains when validating login attempts. Any login attempt to any page that resolves to the server (that is, any domain or IP, using either the `cpanel.` proxy subdomain, or `:2083` port) will be validated against the same set of user/password combinations.

However, considering your example, it should not be possible for one user to use different passwords when logging in to different domains. Service user/password combinations are system-wide and cannot be changed for just one domain.